# Why cannot visit website when Charles app is closed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, web, charles-proxy

*Sorry, my English is poor, the following text if they are not fluent, but also look sorry*

I downloaded a app, Its name is [charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/),Once when I forced it off,I found out when I open it,I can visit website,but when i close it again,Then i try to visit the website,I cannot visit.

Then I try to go to Internet search on a solution,I was required to reboot, or restart my computer,I even re-download the software,Still can not visite the website

Comment: Check your OS proxy settings

Answer (score 15):

I am using Max OS X. Therefore my answer would be only related to OS X.

There are cases when we cannot browse when Charles is installed because it changes your proxy settings when launched. It resets the proxy settings when closed. The settings are of type proxy setting called `Web Proxy(HTTP)` and `Secure WebProxy(HTTPS)`. These are checked when Charles is launched and unchecked when Charles is closed.

However, if Charles crashes for some reason it cannot reset (uncheck) the proxy setting. Hence it blocks the browsing afterwards.

To fix this go to System Preferences -> Network (1) -> Advanced -> Proxies and uncheck `Web Proxy(HTTP)` and `Secure WebProxy(HTTPS)`.

**In short** Uncheck `Web Proxy(HTTP)` and `Secure WebProxy(HTTPS)` and the problem would be fixed -

[image]

Ref: 1 = Select port service you are using. In my case it was "ethernet"

Comment: Resource: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/can-no-longer-browse-without-charles-running/

Comment: This is a right solution though, but doing this every time you close charles, painful right!

Comment: Even If I uncheck these, I am not able to browse. Also, I have *.local, <someIp> in the Bypass proxy box below when Charles closes.

Answer (score 1):

Update now:

I found that when I follow the following steps, you can visit the Web site:

1. Open your charles
2. Click the button at the top of **Proxy**
3. Click the button of **Proxy Settings**
4. Click the button of **Restore Defaults**
5. Click the button at the bottom of **OK**

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the right place for this sort of question(you want a site like [pcadvisor](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forum/helproom-1/) But, it sounds like the proxy you installed is blocking your normal network connection. You can probably just disable whatever virtual device it's created(if it has created one). Or change your proxy settings back to your normal ones. Don't have time to go into detail on that though sorry. Maybe someone else will give you a full answer, but I advise you to post on pcadvisor.